# MySQL - how to join row with minimal value only once

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get row with minimal value for each product. In a simple database. I will outline below. I studied a lot of answers and nothing works unfortunately.

Ive tried some ways of doing this, like self join and it works fine except on the same values it returns doubling values.

```sql
SELECT
  products.id,
  products.name,
  prices.price,
  prices.price_init
FROM products
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = products.id
JOIN(
  SELECT products.id, min(prices.price) as min_price FROM products
  LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = products.id
  GROUP BY products.id
) as min_prices
ON
  min_prices.id = products.id
  AND
  min_prices.min_price = prices.price
```

This query works fine, but doubles the results.

link to sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d106d9a/1

As you can see I need to take price_init field for minimal price.

Thanks.

Comment: There are ties in `price`, hence you are getting multiple results per product. How do you want to handle the ties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want only one row per product -- even when there are multiple minimum prices -- you can filter by the `id` rather than the `price`.

This looks like

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, pr.price, pr.price_init
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     prices pr
     ON pr.product_id = p.id AND
        pr.id = (SELECT pr2.id
                 FROM prices pr2
                 WHERE pr2.product_id = pr.product_id
                 ORDER BY pr2.price
                 LIMIT 1
                );
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d106d9a/5) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note in MySQL 8+, you would instead use window functions:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, pr.price, pr.price_init
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pr.product_id ORDER BY pr.price) as seqnum
      FROM prices pr
     ) pr
     ON pr.product_id = p.id AND pr.seqnum = 1;
```